# Speeding up file read

Tags: java, file, file-io, io, random-access

I have a 1.7G file with the following format:

```
String Long String Long String Long String Long ... etc
```

Essentially, *String* is a key and *Long* is a value in a hashmap i'm interested in initialising before running anything else in my application.

My current code is:

```
  RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile("/home/map.dat","r");
                raf.seek(0);
                while(raf.getFilePointer()!=raf.length()){
                        String name=raf.readUTF();
                        long offset=raf.readLong();
                        map.put(name,offset);
                }
```

This takes about 12 mins to complete and I'm sure there are better ways of doing this so I would appreciate any help or pointer.

thanks

---

**Update as in EJP suggestion?**

EJP thank you for your suggestion and I hope this is what you meant. Correct me if this is wrong

```
DataInputStream dis=null;
    try{
     dis=new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/home/map.dat")));
     while(true){
       String name=dis.readUTF();
       long offset=dis.readLong();
       map.put(name, offset);
     }
    }catch (EOFException eofe){
      try{
        dis.close();
      }catch (IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Comment: What do your profiling results say? Where exactly is the bottleneck?

Comment: 1.7G key value pairs, why are you not using a database instead of a file?

Comment: What do you want to do with that amount of data? I have a strong feeling that you might be using an inefficient approach to this.

Comment: @Perception I don't know what 'one continuous live' might be, but he has specified the file format quite adequately, both verbally and via his code.

Comment: "live" = "line" I would guess.

Comment: @LucasHoepner In which case the question is not just redundant but meaningless, as the file contains binary data.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for your comment. The bottleneck is sys calls as many of you suggested.

Comment: @LucasHoepner Thanks for your comments and no I need that amount of data in the application

Comment: @jlordo worth trying but database access is expensive anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would construct the file so it can be used in place. i.e. without loading this way. As you have variable length records you can construct an array of the location of each record, then place the key in order so you can perform a binary search for data.  (Or you can use a custom hash table)  You can then wrap this with method which hide the fact the data is actually store in a file instead of turned into data objects.

If you do all this the "load" phase becomes redundant and you won't need to create so many objects.

---

This is a long example but hopefully shows what is possible.

```
import vanilla.java.chronicle.Chronicle;
import vanilla.java.chronicle.Excerpt;
import vanilla.java.chronicle.impl.IndexedChronicle;
import vanilla.java.chronicle.tools.ChronicleTest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static final String TMP = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        String baseName = TMP + "/test";
        String[] keys = generateAndSave(baseName, 100 * 1000 * 1000);

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        SavedSortedMap map = new SavedSortedMap(baseName);
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length / 100; i++) {
            long l = map.lookup(keys[i]);
//            System.out.println(keys[i] + ": " + l);
        }
        map.close();
        long time = System.nanoTime() - start;

        System.out.printf("Load of %,d records and lookup of %,d keys took %.3f seconds%n",
                keys.length, keys.length / 100, time / 1e9);
    }

    static SortedMap<String, Long> generateMap(int keys) {
        SortedMap<String, Long> ret = new TreeMap<>();
        while (ret.size() < keys) {
            long n = ret.size();
            String key = Long.toString(n);
            while (key.length() < 9)
                key = '0' + key;
            ret.put(key, n);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    static void saveData(SortedMap<String, Long> map, String baseName) throws IOException {
        Chronicle chronicle = new IndexedChronicle(baseName);
        Excerpt excerpt = chronicle.createExcerpt();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            excerpt.startExcerpt(2 + entry.getKey().length() + 8);
            excerpt.writeUTF(entry.getKey());
            excerpt.writeLong(entry.getValue());
            excerpt.finish();
        }
        chronicle.close();
    }

    static class SavedSortedMap {
        final Chronicle chronicle;
        final Excerpt excerpt;
        final String midKey;
        final long size;

        SavedSortedMap(String baseName) throws IOException {
            chronicle = new IndexedChronicle(baseName);
            excerpt = chronicle.createExcerpt();
            size = chronicle.size();
            excerpt.index(size / 2);
            midKey = excerpt.readUTF();
        }

        // find exact match or take the value after.
        public long lookup(CharSequence key) {
            if (compareTo(key, midKey) < 0)
                return lookup0(0, size / 2, key);
            return lookup0(size / 2, size, key);
        }

        private final StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();

        private long lookup0(long from, long to, CharSequence key) {
            long mid = (from + to) >>> 1;
            excerpt.index(mid);
            tmp.setLength(0);
            excerpt.readUTF(tmp);
            if (to - from <= 1)
                return excerpt.readLong();
            int cmp = compareTo(key, tmp);
            if (cmp < 0)
                return lookup0(from, mid, key);
            if (cmp > 0)
                return lookup0(mid, to, key);
            return excerpt.readLong();
        }

        public static int compareTo(CharSequence a, CharSequence b) {
            int lim = Math.min(a.length(), b.length());
            for (int k = 0; k < lim; k++) {
                char c1 = a.charAt(k);
                char c2 = b.charAt(k);
                if (c1 != c2)
                    return c1 - c2;
            }
            return a.length() - b.length();
        }

        public void close() {
            chronicle.close();
        }
    }

    private static String[] generateAndSave(String baseName, int keyCount) throws IOException {
        SortedMap<String, Long> map = generateMap(keyCount);
        saveData(map, baseName);
        ChronicleTest.deleteOnExit(baseName);

        String[] keys = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(keys));
        return keys;
    }
}
```

generates 2 GB of raw data and performs a million lookups.  It's written in such a way that the loading and lookup uses very little heap. ( << 1 MB )

```
ls -l /tmp/test*
-rw-rw---- 1 peter peter 2013265920 Dec 11 13:23 /tmp/test.data
-rw-rw---- 1 peter peter  805306368 Dec 11 13:23 /tmp/test.index

/tmp/test created.
/tmp/test, size=100000000
Load of 100,000,000 records and lookup of 1,000,000 keys took 10.945 seconds
```

Using a hash table lookup would be faster per lookup as it is O(1) instead of O(ln N), but more complex to implement.

Comment: +1 This plus a memory-mapped file should give a perfect blend of performance, init time, and memory consumption.

Comment: In case the OP cannot alter the file it would be possible to persue this approach by creating an index file with this kind of structure.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I would hardly describe it as 'perfect'. More memory, far more I/O, and far more execution time, than what the OP is doing now. Less startup time, yes.

Comment: @EJP A memory-mapped file is usually served from the system cache. Memory about the same, but probably less, due to Java's various overheads. I only overlook the array of indices; this can be much improved with skip lists (the file must be sorted, though).

Comment: As a side comment, that's pretty much exactly how Lucene's lightning fast indexes work: sorted memory-mapped files with cached skip lists that hold one entry per something like 16 file records.

Comment: Thank you Peter. I've implemented this and used fixed size records this time by transforming the Strings into Integers.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The 17Gb still has to be mapped into the process's address space, and you have overlooked all my other points completely. O(N) I/O operations isn't as efficient as O(1).

Comment: @EJP It's 1.7 GB and if the choice is occupy that much heap vs. system cache, system cache is the better and more scalable option, especially if entries are not all equally often accessed. A huge heap like that means your major GC's turn into a terrible drag. Also, there is not much point in counting memory-mapped file I/O as just any I/O.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But it is 'any I/O'. You've further overlooked that your way creates new objects every lookup instead of once each, so more GC. You also need to account for the inconvenient fact that it is at least twice as slow on test, even if you only read each item once, which isn't a realistic assumption.

Comment: @EJP Minor GC of eden space is virtually for free and without that monstrous structure on the heap, an occasional major GC will get by unnoticed. But the main point is, beyond a certain threshold there is no point in keeping everything in a fixed heap structure; you must forego a certain amount of performance (not much, BTW) to achieve a nicely scalable design, and to have some heap left for anything else your application is up to.

Comment: The lookup of a memory mapped files is slower than in in memory structure.  There is no reason why the data structure or it's time complexity have to be any different. You can write O(1) lookup's using either.  The problem will creating 100's millions of object is the overall impact on the system can be very high.  1.7 GB of raw data can turn into 5+ Gb of memory used as add 5 seconds to the full GC time.  i.e. you might make the lookup take a few micro-second longer but place unacceptible latency delays in your system.  As you scale this solution the difference gets greater.

Comment: All this really depends on the requirements.  If you have Azul's fully concurrent GC JVM, creating so many objects is not an issue, and you could costruct the collection in parallel by reading parts of the file at once (assuming disk IO is not an issue)

Comment: If you want a scalable system with good worst case characteristics, IMHO using a very large Map is not a good idea for the HotSpot JVM, and it will suffer from the OP's original problem of having a long construction time.

Comment: BTW the example above doesn't create object(s) to perform each lookup.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Do you have a method to initialise a HashMap from your chronicle structure?

Comment: @DotNet I only use the Map to build the file. Once the file is created, no Map is required.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've been using yout chronicle structure and it is really  cool (Thanks). I've an excerpt which size exceeds the Max.Integer limit and I guess by default that is not allowed. However, is it possible to define many Chronicles. Each of which corresponds to a String and inside each chronicle many excerpts?

Answer (score 4):

1. Use a DataInputStream wrapped around a BufferedInputStream wrapped around a FileInputStream.
2. Instead of at least four system calls per iteration, checking the length, and the current size and performing who knows how many reads to get the string and the long, just call readUTF() and readLong() until you get an EOFException.

Comment: Thanks EJP for your answer and comments. I've tried this and it takes about 5 mins to upload the data. I used the DataInputStream but I didn't wait for the EOFExcpetion and instead used the sys call available which might have slowed down the reading process.

Comment: @DotNet It did. You added a system call per iteration. Do try it my way. My way there is only one system call per 8k of data. Quite a difference.

Comment: Total Time 4 minutes 22 seconds without the system call "available". Thanks again

Comment: @DotNet It should be *much* quicker than that: well under a minute, including building the Map. Sounds like you didn't use a `BufferedInputStream` as recommended. My timing consistently shows a ratio of RandomAccessFile/DataInputStream/BufferedInputStream in the hundreds, and that's timing the RAF version second to give it the benefit of any caching.

Comment: I've updated the question to include your suggestion. Please let me know if this is not what you meant.

Comment: total time is about 2 mins( ~ 124.11 secs). The previous stat is wrong. Sorry about that.